# SQL - Passing where clause as a varible (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL query that I use that have only the where clause changes. I would like to store the SQL query as one variable and each of the where clauses as separate variable.

Given below is the SQL query that I am using:

Query 1:

```
select a.prod_name,a.prod_cat,b.sale_date 
from products a 
   join sales b on a.id = b.sale_id and b.type=new
```

Query 2:

```
select a.prod_name,a.prod_cat,b.sale_date 
from products a 
  join sales b on a.id = b.sale_id and b.type=modify
```

I plan to write a Python script that would execute this query using variable.

Comment: This may not be desirable from a potential SQL injection point of view.  How are you using Redshift?  If you're using it with a language like Java or C#, then most likely you could write a prepared statement to handle this requirement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the database I am using is Redshift, hence meant that I am using a Redshift DB.

Comment: Also I would be executing this script in Python. Reason I want to use variables is purely for maintenance of the script.

Comment: Can't you write a statement in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go to pass the variable in case of Python. IF you simple would like to go in python, though if your case is this much simple, why to introduce even python, plain simple `shell script` should work for you. Anyways,

```
import psycopg2


def redshift(type_var):


    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='*********', host='*********.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', user='****', password='*******8')
    cur = conn.cursor();

    cur.execute("begin;")

    sql ="select a.prod_name,a.prod_cat,b.sale_date from products a   join sales b on a.id = b.sale_id and b.type='%s'" %(type_var)
    cur.execute(sql)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print("Copy executed fine!"+results)




"""Call one with new"""
redshift('new');
"""Call two with modify"""
redshift('modify');
```